# How to make several mobile devices (both iOS and Android) communicate without using internet

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, wifi-direct

I am currently trying to develop a mobile application for both iOS and Android. It basically will be a game buzzer app, determining which of the players is granted a right to answer a specific questions.

The problem is that I struggle to determine which technology / framework I should use for that. Now, some details:

- In this app there will be a "base" - it is the phone that gives
  "start" signal for all the other players. Each buzzer pressed before this signal corresponds to a false start. Eventually, information
  about which player is granted a right to answer or is penalized due
  to false start should be displayed on the base device.
- App is done for people who have no access to the internet. All the
  communication should exists given ONLY mobile phones with no data
  plan.
- Max number of communicating devices is 9 (1 base and 8 players)

I investigated a lot of resources and this is what I discovered:

- Regular WLAN with TCP sockets and etc won't help, since it assumes that all devices are connected to same wireless access point - it violates my requirements.
- Regular bluetooth won't help either. This would work across a specific platform, but making Android talk to iOS is impossible.
- Situation with Wi-Fi direct is same as with regular bluetooth. Both platforms support this, but Apple's MultipeerConnectivity framework works only with iOS devices.
- Now the last option I am left with is BLE. Both platforms support this and are able to intercommunicate (acting both as central or peripheral devices). However, due to my requirements for an app, I assume that base device should act as peripheral, and according to (sometimes conflicting) articles on Internet, one can't connect several central devices to single peripheral.

Now, my questions:

1. I still assume I might have done some mistakes in the bullet points above, so please, correct me if I am somewhere wrong.
2. Now when I am left only with BLE option, are there any possible solutions to the above issue? Maybe it is possible to use all devices as centrals (?). I recently saw [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5-QyJEIxO74) example, where everything works cool. Sorry in advance, if I said something stupid.
3. Of course, there is a counterexample - FireChat, which employs OpenGarden's [MeshKit](https://www.opengarden.com/meshkit.html). But the framework is not available. I tried communicating OpenGarden people, but no response. Does anyone know if it is planned to go opensource soon, or maybe there exists any analog of this?

Comment: Your base would be the central and each of the players would be a peripheral. This would allow several players to connect to the one base.

Comment: You can use the "base" phone as hotspot, then other devices can communicate with it.

Comment: @Paulw11 But then the base device would be the one initiating connection, and not player - is this correct? It is not a problem, however.

Comment: @jokeman If base device is a hotspot, doesn't it mean that it should be connected to internet?

Comment: The player (peripheral) would advertise its availability via a BLE service and the central would discover that service and make the connection. Once all the players are connected then you would start the round or whatever from the central device

Comment: No, you can create a local wireless network without internet access, can't you?

Comment: @Paulw11 Got it, thanks

Comment: @jokeman I am not sure about it. Do you know the way?

Comment: Hi vash_s, I'm facing a similar connectivity requirement. Curious if you managed to find a solution?

Comment: @S.D Hey, didn't have time to put my hands on HypeLabs but it's easy to get an access and it seems like they have everything I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the Hype SDK by [Hype Labs](https://hypelabs.io/). It's a multi-transport, multi-hop mesh SDK. It supports interoperable Bluetooth Low Energy (and other transports as well). The SDK is currently in private beta but will be made available upon approval of the subscription.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I made a request.